# Django form: how to save every dynamic inputs / rows into database

Tags: jquery, django, postgresql

I am beginner at Django. I am developing a project where a model is **FileAccess** and there has a field named ***files_link***. I have created multiple dynamic inputs/added rows (of this field) using jquery at the Django form. 
 When we submit the form, only the last dynamic input is saved into the database (using **PostgreSQL** database for saving data).

**Example:** Suppose for input 1, input 2, input 3 if there values are ***link1, link2, link3*** and there only last value ***link3*** has been saved into the database. But expected output for ***files_link*** is all the input data ***link1, link2, link3***

[dynamic inputs image of files_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imoC0.png)

Now I want to save every input value/ rows data (of **files_link**) into the database. I need help to solve this out. 
 Thank You in advance.

###### Django 3.1.7

###### PostgreSQL

### models.py

```
class FileAccess(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    files_link = models.CharField(max_length=230)
    revoke_access_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True) 
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
```

### forms.py

```
class FileAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FileAccess
        fields = ['files_link', 'revoke_access_name']
```

### fileaccess_form.html

```
{% extends "blog/basep.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">File Server Access Activation Form</legend>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <div>Files link : <br/>
                        <input type="text" name="files_link[]" value=""/>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-input" title="Add input"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ form.revoke_access_name|as_crispy_field }}                
            </fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var max_input_fields = 10;
        var add_input = $('.add-input');
        var input_wrapper = $('.input-wrapper');
        var new_input = '<div><input type="text" name="files_link" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-input" title="Remove input"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>';
        var add_input_count = 1;
        $(add_input).click(function(){
            if(add_input_count < max_input_fields){
                $(input_wrapper).append(new_input);
                add_input_count++;
            }
        });
        $(input_wrapper).on('click', '.remove-input', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            add_input_count--;
        });
    });
</script>


{% endblock content %}
```

### views.py

```
class FileAccessCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = FileAccess
    form_class = FileAccessForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this with the current `models.py`.

`files_link = models.CharField(max_length=230)`. This only allows you to store a single value, despite your jquery addition in `fileaccess_form.html`.

You could use something like this.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class FileAccess(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    files_link = JSONField()
    revoke_access_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True) 
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
```

You need to modify jquery to provide `files_link = {'link1':input1,'link2':input2,..}`

Otherwise, you will have to move to a NoSQL database like mongoDB, which doesn't have pre-defined columns like PostgreSQL, MySQL etc.